# Why does filter css make text bold?

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, css-filters

I want to set text color based on background-color via css, but for some reason filter css makes text bold, but only for light backgrounds

[image]

```css
.container {
  background-color: white;
  color: white;
}

.text {
  filter: sepia(5) saturate(100) invert(1) grayscale(1) contrast(9);
}

.container-gray {
  background-color: #f0f8ff;
  color: #f0f8ff;
}

.container-black {
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>

<div class="container-gray">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>

<div>Text</div>

<div class="container-black">
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This issue seems to apply only on Chrome browser

Comment: @yunzen I've checked in Firefox. It's actual for it too unfortunately, but almost unnoticeable

Comment: Using Chrome,  I don't really see boldness; are you sure it's not a trick-of-the-eyes? In any case, IMHO, `filter` to me is for decorative things like photos and background images. I'm not shocked that there would be readability issues when applied to text. Clever approach though. For strategic color inversions, I just use variations of my color var's and/or classes, with a suffix. e.g. `var(--color-primary)` versus `var(--color-primary-invert)` and all colors defined in a theme color file rather than buried in CSS filter parameters. Then my app's easily get modes like dark, light, sepia, etc.

Answer (score 0):

At the normal zoom of 100% in Chrome, there does appear to be a difference in boldness, however when you zoom to 500% in Chrome it is clear that there is no difference between the white bold text on a black background and the black bold text on the white background.

[image: Image of two zooms, 100% and 500% in Chrome]

I checked this in Firefox and it is the same there at 500%.

BTW, I zoomed the image produced by running the code in the Stackoverflow code snippet (using the Chrome or Firefox zoom menu option)